# Stop D3.js from redrawing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have an AngularJS web app that is rendering multiple D3 line graphs in an ng-repeat.  The graphs are redrawing repeatedly, even when the backing data isn't changing.  I want to suppress all redraw events (or as many as possible).

The redrawing isn't just randomly infinite.  When something unrelated on the page changes, the redraw is triggered.  None of the data backing the graph is changing, which is what is confusing me.  It almost seems like the graphs redraw whenever the DOM changes.

** Edit (Adding Code Snippets) **

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('alarmAggregator.controllers').controller('HomeCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$routeParams',
    '$log',
    'Source',
    'SaveParameters',
    'GetParameters',
    'IncidentSearch',
    'Waveforms',
    'ConfigItems',
    'usSpinnerService',
    'ImageHelper',
    '$http',
    '$timeout',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, source, saveParameters, getParameters, incidentsSearch, waveforms, configItems, usSpinnerService, imageHelper, $http, $timeout) {

searchService.search($scope.parameters).then(function (result) {
   $scope.incidentsList = result.data;
}).finally(function () {
   $timeout(function () {
      $scope.triggerResizeEvent();
      usSpinnerService.stop('search_spinner');
   }, 1);
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="inci in incidentsList track by inci.incidentId">
   <div ng-repeat="dist in inci.disturbances track by dist.uniqueId">
      <div data-ac-chart="'waveform'" data-ac-data="dist.waveforms"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using rootScope at all for handling the data sources?

Comment: I'm using $scope, and all my data is in one property or another of the $scope object.

Comment: I'm pretty much a novice with AngularJS, and know little more than how to get myself in trouble.  There's a fair chance that I'm using rootScope and it's just being called $scope.  I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: Can you link the codebase to check?

Comment: Most likely your logic is being called due to digest cycle occuring because you're moving your mouse or something. You can find more about scope and digest [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) (not a novice level reading though).

Comment: What do you mean?  Like a JSFiddle?  I don't have one set up, and it will take a long time to get going.  I can put some code snippets up pretty quickly.

Comment: So if I use a Directive to put the data for each graph into it's own scope, would that likely fix the problem?

Comment: Hard to say like that, might be, but a wider view on your app could help understand better.

Comment: I added some stuff.  Not sure if it's helpful.  The app overall is huge, so I'm not sure what exactly is important for you guys to look at.  Thanks for all the help, by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `angular-chart.js` had a watcher set to watch for data changes.  I commented out this line and the page is now lightning fast.  I'm not sure why the data thought it was being changed, but my graphs are static, so it doesn't matter.

This was the line I commented out:

`scope.$watch('[acChart, acData, acConfig]', init, true);`

Comment: If you're using n3-charts, the line in LineChart.js to comment out is: scope.$watch(getDimensions, debouncedResizeEventEmitter, true);